# Why is Visual Studio asking for a reference that is already added?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on a Xamarin project.

I need to get the PackageInfo list. To get the list, I first need to create an instance of the PackageManager class.

Because the class is abstract, I'm overriding all it's methods or else I get errors.

I've successfully overriden all of them except one, GetXml.

I get an error saying:

> You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

However, there already is a reference to System.Xml on the references list.

Could someone please help? Any help would be very much appreciated since I need this for work and I've been stuck with this problem for weeks now.

Thank you so much.

I need to get past this error so I can create an instance of PackageManager, so I can acess PackageInfo, so I can list all the apps on the phone because my app uses an app from a third party but first we want to make sure the third party app is installed.

This is the csproj file as asked

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8</PackageTargetFallback>
    <Version>1.3.4</Version>
    <Company>StrongNet, Lda</Company>
    <Copyright>Copyright © StrongNet 2007-2023</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.3.4.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.3.4.0</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Extensions\MainActivity.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="G4Movel_Android.pdf" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="G4Movel_Android.pdf" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.LocalNotification" Version="10.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="108.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson" Version="108.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.Buttons" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.Core" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfBusyIndicator" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfComboBox" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfListView" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfNumericTextBox" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfNumericUpDown" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPdfViewer" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPopupLayout" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfTabView" Version="20.4.0.44" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2545" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" Version="2.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="G4Movel.Android">
      <HintPath>..\G4Movel.Android\bin\Debug\G4Movel.Android.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v12.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Extensions\CheckedBox.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CheckedBox.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Extensions\SignBox.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SignBox.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Pages\Loan\ListPage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ListPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Pages\Readings\AddPage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Pages\Readings\ListDetailsPage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ListDetailsPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Pages\Readings\ListPage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Pages\WareHouses\WareHousePage.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>WareHousePage.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Pages\Stocks\Add1Page.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Add1Page.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Views\ClientsPageDocumentsAddresses.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ClientsPageDocumentsAddresses.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Pages\Stocks\AddPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Pages\Stocks\ListPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>




The code from MyApp.Android\Services\HelperService.cs
public IList<ApplicationInfo> PM()
{
    IList<PackageInfo> lista = new List<PackageInfo>();
    PackageManager pm2 = new PM2();
    PackageInfoFlags flags = new PackageInfoFlags();
    IList<ApplicationInfo> packages = (IList<ApplicationInfo>)pm2.GetInstalledApplications(flags);
    return (List<ApplicationInfo>)packages;
}
```

This is the interface
public interface IHelperService {
void OpenMPOS(string reference, string value);

```
    bool ScreenOn(bool OnOff);

    void ToastLong(string message, string title);

    void ToastShort(string message, string title);

    IList<ApplicationInfo> PM();
}
```

And this code is from MyApp\Extensions\PaymentMethods.xaml.cs

```
IList<ApplicationInfo> packages = DependencyService.Get<Services.IHelperService>().PM();
```

Comment: Can you please show your .csproj file?

Comment: I've added the csproj file.

Comment: Not sure what's going on. System.XML is a system assembly, but only exists in .NET 4.8, not for a xamarin target. If you don't need all those different targets, I'd try to remove the `PackageTargetFallback` line from the csproj. I think that is deprecated any may confuse the compiler.

Comment: I change my approach. I don't if this is relevant or not but now I'm trying to reach the PackageInfo from the Android Target part of the Project. Maybe this was obvious for you guys out there but I'm not a veteran of Visual Studio or Xamarin. Anyway, it's still not solved because now I don't get errors but the GetInstalledApplications method is still not giving me the info I need.

Comment: I have no experience with this type of installer either. So it's probably best if you create a new question focusing on the new problem.

Comment: What type of installer? What do you mean?

Comment: I meant the package manager.